# How to print "$" in here-document

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

How can I echo "$" in a here-doc in bash?

For example, I want to have a file with the content on remote server like `$ABC=home_dir`.

```
$ ssh hostname sudo -s <<EOF
echo "$ABC=home_dir" > file
EOF
```

But it would be treated as a variable. How can I print a literal `$`?

Comment: you can use single quotes

Comment: That is a lot of indirection going on. Are you sure you can't create the file on the local host and then `scp` it?

Answer (score 81):

If you want to write a here-doc and you don't want ANY of the doc to be expanded or any special characters interpreted, you can quote the label with single quotes, like this:

```
$ cat >file <<'EOF'
echo "$ABC=home_dir"
EOF
```

However, your situation as described in your example is much more complex, because you're really sending this content through ssh, to a remote system, to be run by sudo which is also invoking a shell (and so that shell will expand the content as well).  You're going to need more levels of quoting to get this right, but even with that it still won't work because sudo requires a terminal (so it can ask for a password) and you've redirected from stdin.  Even using `ssh -t` won't help here.

Also I agree with Johan.  It's not clear this is really what you want; note that it's not legal to assign a value to a shell variable reference, so if this file you're trying to create is supposed to be a shell script, it won't work as you've described it.  Maybe if you back up a bit and describe what you *really* want to do, we can help more.

Comment: This is the best answer because it can cater for very long HERE documents. It's (mostly) idiot-proof.

Answer (score 22):

Escape the `$`

```
$ ssh hostname sudo -s <<EOF
echo "\$ABC=home_dir" > file
EOF
```

I do not know what your use case is but usually you want `home_dir=$ABC` instead of `$ABC=home_dir`.

Comment: This solution will work, but is that realy what the OP wants?  It appears to generate a shell script which when executed will store in "file" a string which will dereference ABC for the left-side of the asignment and likely end up storing `=home_dir` to the file?  Of course I don't know what the use case is...

Comment: This will cause a literal `$` to be sent to the remote shell, but then *that* shell will expand `$ABC` before echoing the string to `file`. To write the literal `$` to the file, you'll need another (escaped) backslash: `echo "\\\$ABC=home_dir"`, so that the remote shell receives `echo "\$ABC=home_dir"`.

Answer (score 9):

The cheapest way of escaping would be

```
$ ssh hostname sudo -s << \EOF
echo "$ABC=home_dir" > file
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

You save yourself a level of quoting by sending the string to a `cat` process on the remote end:

```
echo 'echo $ABC=home_dir' | ssh hostname sudo -s "cat > file"
```

The single quotes protect the `$` on the local end, and the string is never seen by the shell on the other because it is read directly by `cat` (via `sudo`), rather than being an argument to another shell command.

With your code, you would need an extra layer of escaping to protect the `$`:

```
$ ssh hostname sudo -s <<EOF
echo "\\\$ABC=home_dir" > file
EOF
```

You need to send a literal `\$` to the remote host, so that the remote shell will write a literal `$` to the file. You could also simplify this by quoting the here-doc marker:

```
$ ssh hostname sudo -s <<\EOF
echo "\$ABC=home_dir" > file
EOF
```