# How to escape $ in here-document

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write some multiline text to a file:

```
cat <<EOF > file
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $sub.$domain.com www.$sub.$domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
EOF
```

For me the problem is that `$server_name$request_uri` should be handled as a string, while domain and sub should be a variable.
So I need to escape that `$` somehow.

Comment: You don't need `;` at the end of every command. Almost every single `;` in the shell grammar may be replaced by a newline.

Comment: @Kusalananda, those are not shell commands, it looks more like nginx configuration.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Doh. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\` to escape the `$`.

```
return 301 https://\$server_name\$request_uri;
```

Comment: No better not do this. Might work for this solution but if you have a lot of stuff inside the EOF you don't want to escape everything one-by-one .. better do it like [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68440/212783) proposes